# An infinite group isomorphic to its own automorphism group, but not complete, part 1

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group, infinite-groups

An example of a non-complete group isomorphic to its own automorphism group is the dihedral group of order $8$.

But, this question is about infinite groups (specifically, non-cohopfian groups).

> **Question:** Do there exist (necessarily infinite) groups $G$ for which $\mathrm{Aut}(G) \cong G$ satisfying the following property?
>
> The center of $G$ is trivial, but $G$ has some outer automorphisms (so the conjugation action $G \to \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is injective but not surjective).

Clearly, if $G$ satisfies this property, then it cannot be cohopfian. In particular, $G$ must be infinite.

**Update**: The other case has been moved to [Part 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4062249/an-infinite-group-isomorphic-to-its-own-automorphism-group-but-not-complete-pa) per [user1729's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4061576/an-infinite-group-isomorphic-to-its-own-automorphism-group-but-not-complete-pa#comment8391484_4061658) below.

Comment: An example (namely, the infinite dihedral group) has already been provided for the first property. Could anyone also think of an example for the second property?

Comment: Yes so your question has been answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The infinite dihedral group is an example with property 1.

Comment: Is there also an example satisfying property $2$?

Comment: @Geoffrey you'd be better asking that in a separate question, linking back to this one.

Comment: OK, the other case has been moved to [Part 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4062249/an-infinite-group-isomorphic-to-its-own-automorphism-group-but-not-complete-pa).

Comment: For Part 2, I was going to suggest a similar example but with the infinite cyclic normal subgroup of the dihedral group replaced by the group $C(2^\infty)$.