# An infinite group isomorphic to its own automorphism group, but not complete, part 2

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group, infinite-groups

[Part 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4061576/an-infinite-group-isomorphic-to-its-own-automorphism-group-but-not-complete-pa) asks for the case where the conjugation action $G \to \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is injective but not surjective. So, now here is the other part (where the map is surjective but not injective).

While Part 1 is about non-cohopfian groups, this part is about non-hopfian groups.

> **Question:** Do there exist (necessarily infinite) groups $G$ for which $\mathrm{Aut}(G) \cong G$ satisfying the following property?
>
> Every automorphism of $G$ is inner, but the center of $G$ is nontrivial (so the conjugation action $G \to \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is surjective but not injective).

Clearly, if $G$ satisfies this property, then it cannot be hopfian. In particular, $G$ must be infinite.

If $H$ is an infinite complete group with no element of order $2$ and also no nontrivial homomorphism to $\mathbb{Z}/2$, then $H \times \mathbb{Z}/2$ does satisfy the above property, but it is clearly not isomorphic to its own automorphism group (because it has an element of order $2$, while its automorphism group is isomorphic to $H$, which has no element of order $2$).

So, there must be another way to construct examples for the above property.

**Note**: The above has been moved from the original question per [user1729's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4061576/an-infinite-group-isomorphic-to-its-own-automorphism-group-but-not-complete-pa#comment8391484_4061658) there.

Comment: How about the semidirect product $C(2^\infty) \rtimes C_2$ where (as in the dihedral group), the action is inversion? That has centre of order $2$.